# Magento Shipping costs using category and weight

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, shipping-method

I'm working with magento 1.9.3 and need to change the shipping costs calculation based on table rate to use weight and category vs destination in the same table rate.

I have some products need to add extra cost based on category vs destination and the rest of products use the normal weight vs destination shipping cost calculation.

Before start coding i would like to have a different approach to find an easy and clean solution to this.

### By now this is the idea

1. Add a new `condition_name` to the CSV named `package_weight_category` with category id as `condition value`
2. Modify the getRate method to find in the DDBB using the categories of the products in the cart and  `condition_name = 'package_weight_category'`
3. If anything is found save the cost
4. Subtract the weight of the products of the categories found to the total weight
5. If `weight >0` find the cost of the updated weight and add it to the cost
6. Return the calculated cost

### My questions are

1. Is this solution functional?
2. It's possible pass the info of the categories and quantity of the products to the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` object?
3. Any better solution or different approach to solve this?

Thanks in advance just for reading